# Contact resistance is messing with the transistor switch

Tags: signal

Hello I have a circuit board here that detects when a plug is detected on a 3.5mm audio jack and a LED is lit up. Since the audio jack has switches, I am using the ring contact and switch since it is unused in the plug.

Here is my circuit for the LED:

[image]

The problem now is, after some investigating it would seem (my theory only) that the ring contact and the ring switch is not "pushed" enough to each other to form a solid connection. I know this since when I try to test both contacts my multi-tester detects a continuity.

In the picture below you can see the LED is on:

[image]

Now if I try to push it in it turns off. Picture below:

[image]

Now I could just easily bent that flap so it would stay in place but when a jack is plugged and unplugged it reverts to its old state. Can the contact resistance be overcome by changing the circuit without changing the actual jack itself ?

Comment: Did you hand-solder the jack? Perhaps the plastic has melted and changed alignment of the switch contacts, or perhaps there is contamination (flux?) on the surface. Try cleaning the contacts by passing a piece of paper soaked in alcohol between them. If that doesn't work then replace the jack.
BTW pushing on the spring could de-tension it and cause it to not make contact normally.

Comment: There are six of these jacks in a board, so i would rule out that it is jack specific, i have tried cleaning the contacts, it did not change anything. I have unsoldered jacks left i will try to not solder anything yet and connect them i will report back for the results :)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the jack that i have chosen are bad one i would say 2/10 of them are bad, i just soldered some fresh ones and 2/10 have good contacts,

Comment: Or you got them too hot while soldering, and 8 of 10 survived.

Comment: that may be the case too, i will look ways how to solder this properly,